# Smart 3-way dimmer switch cuts off at full brightness with incandescent bulbs - won't work with LED bulbs?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I installed TREATLIFE smart switches and dimmers throughout our entire home and there is only one 3-way dimmer switch that just won't seem to properly function.  These smart switches are from Amazon ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08R9JBDHH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08R9JBDHH)).  They work everywhere else in our home with dimmable LED bulbs, but for some reason not on the 3-way circuit in question.

When I first installed the dimmer switch, I tried using it with the incandescent bulbs that were already in the light fixture from the previous homeowners.  Once I increase the brightness above ~90%, the switch clicks off and back on at ~10% brightness.  When I try using the dimmable LED bulbs that I have installed throughout the rest of the house, the lights will flash on and right back off regardless of the brightness the dimmer switch is set to.

I have tried replacing the dimmer switch with another one that I know functions perfectly and I still get the same result.  I have also gone over the wiring multiple times and cannot find any issue there.  I am perplexed as to why the LED bulbs, which draw significantly less power than the incandescent bulbs, are unable to stay on for any length of time.

Can anyone recommend what other steps I can take to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What type of fixture do you have there. You might have a faulty heat or current limiting sensor in it. Hook back up the old dimmer switch and see if the circuit works properly.

Comment: Are you hard-copy deadset on the TREATLIFE smart gizmos?

Comment: That switch lists compatibility with a lot of things, but UL approval isn't one of 'em. Unless you see the UL symbol on the actual packaging (they don't show all 4 sides in the Amazon listing), it's not approved. Just something to consider...

Comment: ETL would be acceptable, but I'm not sure Treatlife has them. It is one of several 'cheap' Chinese brands that just doesn't bother with safety cert.  3-way switches are tricky, you can't just put the smart switch anywhere.  Really, 3-way wiring is very hostile to what consumers want to do.

Comment: try different LED bulbs, some work better with some dimmers than others. There's a lot of variables that cause that, too many to review here, but you can gloss over the details and just try your luck with different kinds. I seem to have good luck with ecosmart bulbs over a variety of dimmers (leading edge, trailing edge, rheostat, etc).